# Using qTip tooltip to load data using AJAX. $(this) isn't what I expect it to be

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I have a grid of many images and each image has a CSS class set to it's unique ID.

Using this javascript code, I'd like to ask my server backend to construct an appropriate HTML summary of said element and return it.

```
$('.tier-items a img').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
        ajax: {
            url: '/Items/GetToolTip/' + $(this).attr("class"), //I assumed that $(this) would contain the element I moused over.
            type: 'GET', // POST or GET
            data: {} // Data to pass along with your request
        }
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-youtube ui-tooltip-shadow'
    },
    position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center',
        effect: function (api, pos, viewport) {
            // "this" refers to the tooltip
            $(this).animate(pos, {
                duration: 600,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false // Set this to false so it doesn't interfere with the show/hide animations
            });
        }
    }
});
```

However it seems that in this case `$(this)` doesn't contain the element that has been moused over to invoke the qTip.

I need to invoke a url like:

```
/Items/GetToolTip/23
```

Instead I get:

```
/Items/GetToolTip/undefined?_=1334977600119
```

**Is there some way to get the element where the QTip was invoked?**

---

Tried this, and still no dice:

```
itemHoverId = 1;

//Construct the id, on mouseenter and use that instead of $(this)
$('.tier-items a img').mouseenter(function () {
    itemHoverId = $(this).attr("class");
    alert(itemHoverId);
});

$('.tier-items a img').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
        ajax: {
            url: '/Items/GetToolTip/' + itemHoverId, //I assumed that $(this) would contain the element I moused over.
            type: 'GET', // POST or GET
            data: {} // Data to pass along with your request
        }
    },
```

The resulting invoke is:

```
/Items/GetToolTip/1?_=1334978818620
```

Comment: never assume what `this` is in JavaScript. It can mean anything depending on how the function it's in is executed, and what the caller provided for `this`

Comment: @Joseph: So what can I do to solve this? (no pun intended)

Comment: `this` isn't defined because you aren't in a function when referencing `this` (you're just defining an object). You *could* iterate over every element in that selector and call `.qtip` on every one. That way `$(this)` would be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is referring to whatever `this` is when the initialization method is called and not your image (ie probably your document ready)
If you need an individual url for each img you could create a qtip widget individually

```
$('.tier-items a img').each(function() { $(this).qtip({
content: {
    text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
    ajax: {
        url: '/Items/GetToolTip/' + $(this).attr("class"), //I assumed that $(this) would contain the element I moused over.
        type: 'GET', // POST or GET
        data: {} // Data to pass along with your request
    }
}, ....
```

Comment: This works more or less, now the id is being used correctly but this weird string is being appended and the resulting string is: `http://localhost:35082/Items/GetToolTip/2?_=1334979064149`.

Comment: Looks like a timestamp, its probably appended to prevent caching by qtip

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Thank you for your help. :)